# undefined local variable or method in Ruby on Rails app OneMonth Strip

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this error and am searching for the right place to look in my code to figure out why it's showing up. I've searched for where to define a variable or method but haven't figured it out. Any suggestions?

NameError in ChargesController#create
undefined local variable or method `product' for #

Extracted source (around line #13):
11
12
13
14
15
16

```
      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer    => customer.id,
        :amount      => product.price_in_cents,
        :description => product.full_description,
        :currency    => 'usd'
      )
```

These two lines are the ones with the error. 
            :amount      => product.price_in_cents,
            :description => product.full_description,

Here is my product.rb models

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
def full_description
 "#{self.title} #{self.subtitle}"
end
def price_in_cents
 (self.price * 100).to_i
end
```

end

Here is my charges controller

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
    def create
      # Amount in cents
      @amount = 500

      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => params[:stripeEmail],
        :card  => params[:stripeToken]
      )

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer    => customer.id,
        :amount      => product.price_in_cents,
        :description => product.full_description,
        :currency    => 'usd'
      )

     purchase = Purchase.create(email: params[:stripeEmail], card: params[:stripeToken], 
        amount: product.price_in_cents, description: charge.description, currency: charge.currency,
        customer_id: customer.id, product_id: product.id, uuid: SecureRandom.uuid)

        redirect_to purchase

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to charges_path
    end
```

end

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing the product variable in your create method but you haven't created it.

You probably need someting like

```
product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
```

Comment: Thanks! That was close but it sent me on the right track. I'd defined prduct in another controler and needed to add how the product is tracked product = Product.find_by_sku("GROHACK1")